# python scipy differential evolution optimization fails with workers not 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, scipy, differential-evolution

I am trying to use the `workers` parameter of [the scipy differential evolution algo](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html).

When I put it as 1, my script runs with no issues.
If I put something different, it fails with the following traceback :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py", line 419, in __call__
    return self._mapfunc(func, iterable)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py", line 878, in _calculate_population_energies
    parameters_pop[0:nfevs]))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py", line 422, in __call__
    raise TypeError("The map-like callable must be of the"
TypeError: The map-like callable must be of the form f(func, iterable)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_parallel.py", line 323, in <module>
    optimizer(args.asset_class, udl, tenor, args.criteria, params_decay, params, couch_server, args.num_workers)
  File "main_parallel.py", line 269, in optimizer
    maxiter=5, workers=num_workers, mutation=(0.5, 1.5), recombination=0.8)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py", line 306, in differential_evolution
    ret = solver.solve()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py", line 745, in solve
    self.population[self.feasible]))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py", line 883, in _calculate_population_energies
    raise RuntimeError("The map-like callable must be of the"
RuntimeError: The map-like callable must be of the form f(func, iterable), returning a sequence of numbers the same length as 'iterable'
```

Could someone please help in explaining how to use this parameter (specific objective function ? other constraints ?) ?

Also an example of a simple python differential evolution optimization using multiple cores would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical piece of the [differential evolution documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) regarding the usage of workers is the caveat that when `worker != 1`, it

> [...] Requires that `func` be pickleable

There are several hints in the errors raised which indicate the `func` is not pickleable, namely

> ```
>     self._mapfunc(func, iterable)
>     ...
>     self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
>     ...
> TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
> ```

Clearly, there was an attempt at pickling `func` made which failed due, presumably, to `func` not being pickleable. It looks like `workers` is attempted to be interpreted as a *map-like or callable*, as the other signature in the documentation indicates. Predictably this fails as well since `workers` is in fact an `int`.

The documentation contains a [complete example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html#examples) where `workers != 1` which works correctly,

```py
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution, rosen
bounds = [(0,2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2)]
result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, updating='deferred',
                                workers=-1)
result.x, result.fun
```

If you refactor the `func` being used in `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution` to be serializable via [pickling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-python-pickling-example/) you should be able to use `workers != 1` successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do you know that the culprit is args.asset_class ? It's just a string so I would assume its handling is built-in.

Comment: @Chapo That is a mistake, I misread the error statement. I would need to see how you call `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution` to tell you what needs to be refactored for pickling

Comment: `result_diff_evo = differential_evolution(func=optimizer_function, bounds=bounds, args=(
            init_params_names, df, criteria, params_decay[udl][tenor]["first_date"], params_decay[udl][tenor]["busdays"], params_decay[udl][tenor]["coeff"],
            params_decay[udl][tenor]["spot_start"], params_decay[udl][tenor]["iv_start"], params["verbose"], folder, tested_params,), init=pop_denorm,
                                                 maxiter=5, workers=num_workers, mutation=(0.5, 1.5), recombination=0.8, print=True)` is the actual line

Comment: @Chapo The solution to your problem is to refactor `optimizer_function` to be serializable via pickling

Comment: all of the params are fairly simple except for `tested_params` which is obtained through `tested_params = open(f"tested_params.csv", "w")`. Could it be the issue ?

Comment: ok fair enough. Will have to check if i can pickle an open file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205981/discussion-between-chapo-and-william-miller).

Comment: @Chapo Good to hear it, glad I could help